# How to decompose this sum?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to decompose the sum $ x\sum_{j=1...n} \frac{1}{x+y_j}$ into $f(x)*g(y_1,...,y_n)$ for some functions $f,g$ if that is possible. This would be useful to reduce computational load in my code. I tried using means (arithmic, geometric, etc.) but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$f(x)\,g(y)=\frac1{x+y}.$$

Taking the logarithm,

$$\log f(x)+\log g(y)=-\log\left(x+y\right).$$

Now if we take the partial derivative on $x$,

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-\frac1{x+y}$$ and the dependency on $y$ cannot be avoided. So even for a single $y$ what you are trying to obtain is impossible.